# Received Signal Strength Calculation for Probabilistic Line of Sight Channel

Tags: digital-communications

**Scenario:**
Given a UAV which emits a beacon and the beacon is received by a node on the ground. The node calculates the received signal strength. Considering the channel is Probabilistic LoS, the average path loss is given as:

$$L_{a, k}^{av}(t) = \left[P^{LoS}\eta^{LoS} + P^{NLoS}\eta^{NLoS}\right]\left(\lambda_o d_{a, k}\right)^\alpha$$

Where

- $\lambda_o = \frac{4\pi f_r}{c}$
- the probability of line of sight is given as:
  $$P^{LoS}(t) = \frac{1}{1 + A\exp\left(-B\left[\left(\frac{h_a}{d_{a, k}(t)}\right) - A\right]\right)}$$
- $h_a$ is the platform height
- $A$ and $B$ are environment dependent parameters
- $d_{a, k}$is the distance between the UAV and node
- $c$ is the speed of light
- and $f_r$ is carrier frequency.
- $P^{LoS}, \eta^{LoS}, P^{NLoS}, \eta^{NLoS}, \alpha, f_r$
  are the probability of line of sight, mean additional loss for line of sight, probability of non-line of sight, mean additional loss for probability of line of sight, path loss exponent and carrier frequency, respectively.
  Assume the transmit power is $P_t$ and received power is $P_r$. And the antenna gains at transmit and receive side are, $G_t$ and $G_r$ respectively.

**Goal:**
My final aim is to get the distance from platform to node, the node receives the beacon from platform and based on the received power has to ascertain its approximate distance to platform.

**Question:**
What would be relation for received power at the node, considering the given average path loss above from the platform.

Comment: "RSSI" is not uniformly defined. Every standard, or sometimes every device, just invents a formula for that, which incorporates received signal power, noise floor, interference power, clock errors etc. You're missing a transmit power specification, so you can't even make any statement on the received signal strength, so what you've got is insufficient for that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller by the sounds of it, I think you might have answered the question or at least cleared up confusion that there is no absolute equation and it depends on the platform

Comment: Why do you want to use RSSI? Is it required to be used for some reason? I may be wrong, but I can't figure out what you'd be able to do with RSSI as opposed to say received SNR?

Comment: In my project I intend to use RSSI to calculate the distance of the node from the platform. The envisaged protocol I intend to develop deems it necessary. RSSI depends on the distance, hence the node must be cognizant of its distance from the platform. I was just not sure how to put it all together. Assuming we have a transmit power as Pt of the beacon.

Comment: Further I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: again, RSSI is just *some* relatively arbitrary number that might or might not be closely related to all this. There's no "canonical definition" of what a RSSI is! What you're really looking for is the loss, and you already have a formula for that.

Comment: @Khurram In other words, your question cannot be answered without first defining RSSI (using an equation! not a verbal description).

Comment: I have further edited my question for clarity. My final aim is to get the distance from platform to node, the node receives the beacon from platform and based on the received power has to ascertain its approximate distance to platform.

Comment: Hm, isn't $P^{LoS}=1-P^{NLoS}$, anyway? Or do I need to understand "NLOS" as "indirect path, which might *coexist* with a direct path"? Also, you still can't even bound anything here – the mean of the losses of these scenarios is not enough, you'll need some knowledge about the probability density of the loss of the LOS and the NLOS scenario.

Comment: NLOS is non line of sight path and LOS is Line of sight path, based on the probability of these two we compute the average path loss as these two factor in that. Either there is going to be a direct line of sight or non line of sight based on probability. The mean losses are the parametric values and in literature have been ascertained for various environmental settings, like Urban, Rural.

Comment: Question has been edited further for clarity